# Confirmation of Proof: $\cos^2(x) = \frac 12\big(1+\cos(2x)\big)$ using Euler's identity?

Tags: trigonometry

> > How can I prove the following equation: $$\cos^2(x) = \frac 12\big(1+\cos(2x)\big),\tag1$$ using Euler's identity? $$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0.\tag*{$\begin{align} \because e^{i\theta} &= \cos\theta + i\sin\theta \\ &= \text{cis} \ \theta \end{align}$}$$

I have tried equating Euler's equation to cos on one side and squaring that but haven't had luck reducing it to the desired form as outlined in $(1)$.

Comment: $(\frac 12 (e^{ix} + e^{-ix}))^2 = \frac 12 + \frac 14(e^{2ix} + e^{-2ix})$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the goal of the problem is to use Euler's Identity in particular, but the proposition can be established by integrating both sides of: $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$. I've posted such an answer below just for fun (I'm not sure whether you've covered Calculus since the question is tagged only with trigonometry!)

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}e^{ix}&=\cos x+i\sin x\\e^{-ix}&=\cos x-i\sin x\\\hline\color{red}{\cos x}&=\color{blue}{\dfrac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}\\\cos^2x&=\dfrac14(e^{2ix}+2+e^{-2ix})\\&=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac12\left(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}+2\right)\\&=\dfrac12\left\{1+\dfrac12(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix})\right\}\\\color{red}{\cos^2x}&=\color{blue}{\dfrac12(1+\cos 2x)}\end{align}$$

Comment: The exponential property of $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ is a consequence of the addition formulas for circular functions. Or one may prefer to define the symbol $e^{ix} $ without using circular functions and then prove the link to circular functions.

Answer (score 0):

An **alternative approach** (without Euler's Identity).

Recall that $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$. Negate both sides and integrate:$$\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) + C = \cos^2(x)$$

Plugging in $x = 0$ yields:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cos(0) + C = \cos^2(0)$$

and, noting that $\cos(0) = 1$, this latter equation becomes:

$$\frac{1}{2} + C = 1$$

from which we conclude that $C = 1/2$. Plugging this value of $C$ into the first centered equation above and factoring out a $1/2$ leaves us with the desired identity:

$$\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x) + 1) = \cos^2(x)$$

Comment: In the traditional approach derivatives of circular functions also depend on the addition formulas. But it is possible to revert this and instead let the addition formulas depend on the derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

A short and simple solution:

$Cos^2x=Cos^2x-Sin^2x+Sin^2x=Cos2x+1-Cos^2x$

$2Cos^2x=Cos2x+1$

⇒$Cos^2x=\frac{1}{2}(1+Cos2x)$